# Multiline plot for each id

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to plot multiple lines in Python for this dataset: (x = year, y = freq)

```
Student_ID  Year    Freq
A           2012    6
B           2008    22
C           2009    18
A           2010    7
B           2012    13
D           2012    31
D           2013    1
```

where each student_id has data for different years. count is the result of a groupby.
I would like to have one line for each student_id.

I have tried with this:

```
df.groupby(['year'])['freq'].count().plot()
```

but it does not plot one line for each student_id.

Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you for your help

Comment: So you want one graph with 4 lines, where the x-axis is several years and the y-axis is the count over time?

Comment: Yes, Josh. This is an example of the dataset. I would have more than 4 lines, but I would like to understand how to plot a line for each of them. y-axis is the count over time and in the x-axis there are years

Comment: `seaborn` is made for this type of graph: `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='year', y='freq', hue='Student_ID')`.

Comment: Thank you Quang Hoang. Could I use it also in case I have to count Frequency of ids per year, in case I would not have that field in my dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure from your question if you wanted `count` (which in your example is all ones) or `sum`, so I solved this with `sum` - if you'd like `count`, just swap it out for `sum` in the first line.

```
df_ = df.groupby(['Student_ID', 'Year'])['Freq'].sum()
print(df_)

> Student_ID  Year
A           2010     7
            2012     6
B           2008    22
            2012    13
C           2009    18
D           2012    31
            2013     1
Name: Freq, dtype: int64

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for student in set(a[0] for a in df_.index):
    df_[student].plot(ax=ax, label=student)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Josh for your help. May I ask you if it would be possible to do the same, in case, instead of column `Freq`, I have to create a new column by counting individual `student_id` per `year`?

Comment: Do you mean just one line plotting number of students over year? If so you could do `df.groupby('Year')['Student_ID'].count()` (or `z.groupby('Year')['Student_ID'].count().plot()`)

Comment: Yes. Would I be able to apply what you suggested in case I had about 100 different student's ids? Thank you for your help Josh

Comment: You're welcome, and yes you would. Give it a shot, and if it doesn't work maybe open up a new question. Good luck!  (Also note that my comment above should read `df.groupby` in place of `z.groupby`.)

Comment: Thank you Josh. Yes, I have opened a new question for a new problem. Thank you for your help and for your time